# Mock only selected properties in Spring Environment

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to be able to use a test properties files and only override a few properties. Having to override every single property will get ugly fast.

This is the code I am using to test my ability to mock properties and use existing properties in a test case

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
@TestPropertySource(
      locations = { "classpath:myapp-test.properties" },
      properties = { "test.key = testValue" })
public class EnvironmentMockedPropertiesTest {

   @Autowired private Environment env;
   // @MockBean private Environment env;

   @Test public void testExistingProperty() {
      // some.property=someValue
      final String keyActual = "some.property";
      final String expected = "someValue";
      final String actual = env.getProperty(keyActual);
      assertEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test public void testMockedProperty() {
      final String keyMocked = "mocked.test.key";
      final String expected = "mockedTestValue";
      when(env.getProperty(keyMocked)).thenReturn(expected);
      final String actual = env.getProperty(keyMocked);
      assertEquals(expected, actual);
   }

   @Test public void testOverriddenProperty() {
      final String expected = "testValue";
      final String actual = env.getProperty("test.key");
      assertEquals(expected, actual);
   }

}
```

What I find is:

- `@Autowired private Environment env;`

  - `testExistingProperty()` and `testOverriddenProperty()` pass
  - `testMockedProperty()` fails
- `@MockBean private Environment env;`

  - `testMockedProperty()` passes
  - `testExistingProperty()` and `testOverriddenProperty()` fail

Is there a way to achieve what I am aiming for?

Dependencies:

```
<spring.boot.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
...
<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Starter for testing Spring Boot applications with libraries including JUnit,
   Hamcrest and Mockito -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am assuming you want to achieve this by only using one Environment env variable which has both ability to work on mocked and real data right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i have made this work, you need to use Mockito to accompish what you are looking for:

**Maven Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**Test Class Set up**

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.util.AopTestUtils.getTargetObject;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
@TestPropertySource(
      locations = { "classpath:myapp-test.properties" },
      properties = { "test.key = testValue" })

public class AnswerTest {

    // This will be only for injecting, we will not be using this object in tests.
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // This is the reference that will be used in tests.
    private Environment envSpied;

    // Map of properties that you intend to mock
    private Map<String, String> mockedProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        mockedProperties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mockedProperties.put("mocked.test.key_1", "mocked.test.value_1");
        mockedProperties.put("mocked.test.key_2", "mocked.test.value_2");
        mockedProperties.put("mocked.test.key_3", "mocked.test.value_3");

        // We use the Spy feature of mockito which enabled partial mocking
        envSpied = Mockito.spy((Environment) getTargetObject(env));

        // We mock certain retrieval of certain properties
        // based on the logic contained in the implementation of Answer class
        doAnswer(new CustomAnswer()).when(envSpied).getProperty(Mockito.anyString());
    }
```

**Test case**

```
    // Testing for both mocked and real properties in same test method
    @Test public void shouldReturnAdequateProperty() {
        String mockedValue = envSpied.getProperty("mocked.test.key_3");
        String realValue = envSpied.getProperty("test.key");

        assertEquals(mockedValue, "mocked.test.value_3");
        assertEquals(realValue, "testValue");
    }
```

**Implementation of Mockito's Answer interface**

```
    // Here we define what should mockito do:
    // a) return mocked property if the key is a mock
    // b) invoke real method on Environment otherwise
    private class CustomAnswer implements Answer<String>{

        @Override
        public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            Object[] arguments = invocationOnMock.getArguments();
            String parameterKey = (String) arguments[0];

            String mockedValue = mockedProperties.get(parameterKey);

            if(mockedValue != null){
                return mockedValue;
            }

            return (String) invocationOnMock.callRealMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Try it out, and let me know if all is clear here.

Comment: Where is `getTargetObject()` coming from?

Comment: sorry forgot about the imports. I have updated the post

Comment: Well, it's substantially more complicated, but it works, so thank you very much. :) I guess `@MockBean` simply doesn't do what I wanted, which is a shame: I thought the idea of mocking is that you only override the things you actually need (or is that spying?).

Comment: Those are two different concepts. You needed a spy here, but on top of that you needed conditional resolution based on params, and that i have only encountered few times in my career.